# Clarification on going back with tableviewcell in edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

A clarification regarding the crash in UITableView.
I enabled the canEditRowAtIndexpath and commitEditingStyle in UITableViewController.

When I swipe the cell left I can see the delete button which is normal. The problem is when I try to go back when the cell is in edit mode my app got crashed. Nothing else.

Though I solved it by setting the **tableView.editing** **false** on viewWillDisappear, I dont really know the cause for the crash. Just curious to know the reason behind it and why it doesn't set the editing false automatically when the user navigates to other screen.

Pl do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: lldb isn't an exception - it is the debugger prompt.

Comment: But what is the actual exception message?

Comment: There's no message. I just got (lldb)..

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint (Blue mark in the margin)?  What happens when you press the |> button on the debugger controls?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)

Comment: And what line does the debugger stop on? http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: _class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {_ I used those debugger controls but it shows only this line.

Comment: Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint?  I'm assuming you are writing in Swift?  Have you tried writing in Objective-C?  Swift's exception reporting seems to be particularly woeful :P

Comment: yes , I am writing in Swift. I didn't try Obj-C. Let me give it a try. I am tired of this. Though its not a big deal, just trying to find out the reason. Thanks for your valuable time Paul. :)